# pythonw.exe can't upload file to Amazon S3

Tags: python, boto3, pythonw

I've written a Python script which takes screenshot of my pc at a certain interval and send that screenshot to my S3 bucket. When I run my script with python command, it works, but when I run this script as a background task with pythonw.exe command, the screenshot capturing operation works- but nothing uploads to S3.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import Image
import ImageGrab
import getpass
import boto3
import threading
from random import randint


s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
username =  getpass.getuser()


#---------------------------------------------------------
#User Settings:
SaveDirectory=r'C:\Users\Md.Rezaur\Dropbox\Screepy_App\screenshot'
ImageEditorPath=r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\mspaint.exe'

def capture_and_send():
    interval = randint(10,30)
    threading.Timer(interval, capture_and_send).start ()
    img=ImageGrab.grab()
    saveas=os.path.join(SaveDirectory,'ScreenShot_'+time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')+'.jpg')
    fname = 'ScreenShot_'+time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')+'.jpg'
    img.save(saveas, quality=50, optimize=True)
    editorstring='""%s" "%s"'% (ImageEditorPath,saveas) 
    data = open(fname, 'rb')
    s3.Bucket('screepy').put_object(Key=username+'/'+fname, Body=data)

capture_and_send()
```

If you didn't configure your aws credentials, install the aws-cli and run the command:

```
aws configure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fname` variable contains *only* the file name with no path information. So you're saving the file to the path named by `saveas` which contains full path information. When you're opening `fname`, it will be trying to load it from the current directory. The problem is not a difference between `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe`, but just where you're running the script from. In the first case, you must be launching the script from the `SaveDirectory` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Alex Taylor.

After booting up the pythonw.exe program couldn't find the current directory.
The following line has been changed:

```
data = open(SaveDirectory+'\\'+fname, 'rb')
```